# How to pass a VF controller list to a VF/javascript table

Tags: apex, javascript

Please I need to put a list var "who I received from controller" in the JavaScript table and brows it.
This my code :

```
Public class Controller_OlympusLR_addMultipleVouchers
{
    public ValidateField_OlympusLR var {get;set;}

    public Controller_OlympusLR_addMultipleVouchers(ApexPages.StandardSetController stdcontroller)
    {
        var = new List<Olympus_Server__c>();
        var = [select Olympus_Project__r.Name ,MAC_Address__c from Olympus_Server__c where Olympus_Project__c != null ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the inconsistent handling of trailing commas in arrays in JavaScript, it is probably simplest to generate the JavaScript array text in Apex and just output it in the Visualforce. So the aim is to generate a string of this form:

```
["abc","def","ghi"]
```

To do that you can first build the array in Apex and then use a [JSON.serialize](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_serialize) call (which will correctly escape the array values):

```
Public class Controller_OlympusLR_addMultipleVouchers
    public String array {get; set;}
    public Controller_OlympusLR_addMultipleVouchers(ApexPages.StandardSetController sc)
    {
        String[] items = new String[] {};
        for (Olympus_Server__c os : [
                select Olympus_Project__r.Name, MAC_Address__c
                from Olympus_Server__c
                where Olympus_Project__c != null
                order by MAC_Address__c
                ]) {
            // ... or whichever field you require here
            items.add(os.MAC_Address__c);
        }
        array = JSON.serialize(items);
    }
}
```

Then in the Visualforce you can just assign the value to a JavaScript variable:

```
 var array = ["abc","def","ghi"];
```

like this:

```
<script>
var array = {!array};
// For debugging to check that the array values are there
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}
// Your logic
...
</script>
```

Use your browser's "View Source" feature to check the text that ends up in the page and also check the JavaScript console to make sure there are no errors there.

Comment: thinks its working

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var s = [];
    <apex:repeat value="{!var}" var="thing">
      s.push('{!JSENCODE(thing)}');
    </apex:repeat>    
  </script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thinks for your response ,but its not working and i need to get value whith javascript not with json; if i put in javascript var x = '{!var[0].MAC_Address__c}' i get the value but i mlokingfor a method who i brows all table.